# Reporting the existence of some particular public place in a city

Tags: phrase-choice

Which of the following sentences is better?

> There is one museum in this city.

> This city has one museum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these is fine, and there's no particular difference between them.

However, you use **one** museum in such a short sentence only if you mean that the city has **only one**  museum. If this is not the case, you say **a** museum unless you are going to single out one particular museum you are talking about.

> There is one museum in this city you must not miss.
>
> This city has one museum with an international reputation.